# Is it a good user experience to build drawer items from web json response?

Tags: android, json, user-interface, user-experience

We were told to build android side menu from web JSON object. the thing is design can be complex and might contain expendable list-view. and another drawback of using this approach is we first have to get the data via network request and pull strip down data and then build the side menu. so first-time drawer activity initializes it will be doing alot of background activity already. and in the meantime if user is clicks the drawer toggle im sure its going to freeze the user to that screen since its not even populated. so im asking for the suggestion is it a good user experience to even integrate this way. suggestions and discussions welcome

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to do network transactions in a [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html). So drawer menu performance is not affected while it's waiting for the data to arrive.

I suggest you initiate your drawer menu at first with all the designed structure and local data (username, avatar or etc.) and a loading icon to indicate the drawer is not shown completely yet. Once you get the data from server you re-initiate it and replace that indicator with menu items.

Comment: the main question is 'is it a good user experience to block user while we populate a simple thing which could be native?'

Comment: You said you were told to do so. It means you have no other choice. Is it a good user experience? It depends on what kind of items going to be shown in the drawer. Is it product categories or some simple static items. But generally no user wants to wait for contents at all.